# Storyboard's UILabel multiple lines of text not work in iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, uilabel

My storyboard using AutoLayout，I drag a `UILabel` into `UIViewController`, and set it's `numberOfLines` property is 0, not set its constraints.

When I try to use the code to change its height, but it not works.

Please look at the following pictures：
[image]
[image]

In ViewController.m

```
#define MXGetScreenWidth            [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSString *text = @"Why not work, I was so sad in my deep heart. I need to study hard, talk less and work more.";
   NSMutableAttributedString *contentAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
[contentAttributedString addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.f]}
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
   CGSize contentSize = [contentAttributedString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(MXGetScreenWidth-10*2, 60)
                                                           options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                           context:nil].size;
   self.tipsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 52, MXGetScreenWidth-10*2,
                                  tipsSize.height>=25.f?tipsSize.height:25.f);
}
```

What happened in iOS9? Thanks for your precious answers.

Comment: set the line break to word wrap

Comment: aslo give the width constraint

Answer (score 0):

With `AutoLayout` enabled try this:

```
[label setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:MXGetScreenWidth];
```